# Sending fullscreen, disappearing SMSs to an iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile, sms, notifications, mobile-phones

Where I live (Copenhagen, Denmark) there is a taxi company which offers to send you an SMS when the car you ordered is about to arrive.

The SMSs are unlike any I have received on my iPhone in that they appear fullscreen and are not saved to the SMS application. See this screenshot:

[image: A full screen SMS on an iPhone]

As soon as you press "Dismiss" the message is completely gone. No trace of it in the SMS application.

I was thinking that the ability to do this could be useful for apps in some way. Perhaps offered instead of a regular push notification for super important things. But most of all I am curious to learn what's going on.

- Is this a regular SMS or some sort of cell network alert?
- How can these be sent? Is it content formatting which triggers this special display or is it a protocol feature?
- How would they appear on other phones?
- If it is not a regular SMS but some sort of network alert would it be possible to send one to a 3G-enabled iPad?

Comment: Maybe the local taxi company is in partnership with your wireless carrier.  Either way, that is neat.

Comment: Are you using a taxi application?

Comment: I'm not using a taxi application. And they have no way of knowing that I'm on an iPhone, so this has to be something that works across all phones.

Comment: What information have you provided them? Do they just have your phone number? I'm guessing you just call, order a taxi and give them your phone number, then when they are close they send you a message?

Comment: you should test flash SMS because many carries ignore this configuration (not only in US)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prefix your text messages with `*go`.

See [this link](http://www.mattg.co.uk/words/iphone_messages/)!

Be sure to see [this link](http://blog.alltechrelated.com/2010/09/20/send-class-0-sms-messages-to-iphones-with-flash-sms/) (link is now dead so view the [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20111214094600/http://blog.alltechrelated.com/2010/09/20/send-class-0-sms-messages-to-iphones-with-flash-sms) version) too as it may cost an additional charge to send them. After research only GSM providers over seas (not in the US) can do this.

Comment: Yes, that's the same mechanism! I see that they offer an SMS delivery report as a fullscreen alert, but I still can't see how they do it.

Comment: Can you confirm your phone is not jailbroken? The link shows a jailbroken phone.

Comment: Fantastic! Class 0 SMS. Indeed my phone is not jailbroken, so it had to be some official mechanism. May you get many upvotes on this. :-)

Comment: The second link is dead (the new blog is http://alltechrelated.wordpress.com, but the original article is no longer there), but an old version can be retrieved on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20111214094600/http://blog.alltechrelated.com/2010/09/20/send-class-0-sms-messages-to-iphones-with-flash-sms).

Answer (score 6):

I've just written up a blog post on these class 0 or "flash" messages [here](http://blog.richpollock.com/2014/06/class-0-sms-messages/). They look slightly different now in iOS 7:

[image: Class 0 message on iOS 7]

The SMS [specification](http://www.3gpp.org/DynaReport/23040.htm) has this to say about class 0 messages:

> When a mobile terminated message is class 0 and the MS has the
>   capability of displaying short messages, the MS [mobile] shall display the
>   message immediately and send an acknowledgement to the SC [service center] when the
>   message has successfully reached the MS irrespective of whether there
>   is memory available in the (U)SIM or ME. The message shall not be
>   automatically stored in the (U)SIM or ME.

I had a look into the technical details of these a bit more and it turns out that the class is set using the last 2 bits of the "Data Coding Scheme" (DCS) field of the SMS-DELIVER and SMS-SUBMIT [protocol data units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_data_unit). The DCS field is a single octet, the use of which varies depending on the value of bits 4-7. A message class can be specified in the cases where bits 4-7 are set to either 00xx or 1111.

In the former case, bit 5 indicates whether or not the text is compressed, bit 4 indicates whether a message class has been specified, bits 2 and 3 indicate the character set and bits 0 and 1 specify the class (if bit 4 is equal to 1). So, for instance, 00010000 (0×10) would indicate an uncompressed class 0 message using the GSM 7 bit default alphabet and 00110100 (0×34) would represent a compressed class 0 message with an 8 bit-encoded UD field.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a Flash SMS, and works on other phones too. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service#Flash_SMS